# me sale error con un bean: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'defaultMwMessageSender'

Tags: java, spring-boot

Estoy intentado consumir un servicio SOAP y poner el bean HttpComponentsMessageSender en la clase aplication, y usarlo en otra clase, pero no me reconoce el Bean y me manda el error:

```
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'defaultMwMessageSender'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}",
```

Así tengo mi clase Aplication:

```
@ComponentScan("appws")
@PropertySource(value = "file:${VARIABLE_WS}/appws.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
        DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class })
public class appwsApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {


  @Bean
    public HttpComponentsMessageSender defaultMwMessageSender() {
        HttpComponentsMessageSender messageSender = new HttpComponentsMessageSender();
        messageSender.setCredentials(new UsernamePasswordCredentials(usuario,password);     
        return messageSender;
    }
```

Y mi clase en la que quiero usar el Bean:

```
@Configuration
public class ClientConfig { 
  @Autowired
  public HttpComponentsMessageSender defaultMwMessageSender;



@Bean
  public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller(){
      Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
      marshaller.setContextPath("appws.soap.mat");
      return marshaller;
  }  

  @Bean
  public Client RecuperarClient(Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller) {
    Client client = new Client();
    client.setMarshaller(jaxb2Marshaller);
  client.setUnmarshaller(jaxb2Marshaller);
  client.setMessageSender(defaultMwMessageSender);
  return client;
  }
```